# virtualenv ImportError: No module named urllib3

Tags: ubuntu, virtualenv

I installed virtualenv on ubuntu. However, when I try to create a virtualenv I get an error. My Zenv folder does not contain "activate". How can I fix it? I would do this frequently. This is the first time I get this error.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-24-181:~$ virtualenv Zenv
New python executable in /home/ubuntu/Zenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /home/ubuntu/Zenv/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/utils.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/compat.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
ImportError: No module named urllib3
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 703, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 904, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 861, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 781, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/ubuntu/Zenv/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I had the python version from my anaconda that was interfering with the python I had in /usr/bin. This worked for me:

```
virtualenv my-virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 1):

'**virtualenv venv**' may use python in anaconda, which may cause the problem.

'**virtualenv venv -p /usr/bin/python**' may meet this problem, but it uses python default in your system, not python in anaconda.

so you can use '**pip install virtualenv**' before you install anaconda, and **Do not** install virtualenv in anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me

```
pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple urllib3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/3b/f0/e763169124e3f5db0926bc3dbfcd580a105f9ca44cf5d8e6c7a803c9f6b5/urllib3-1.16.tar.gz#md5=fcaab1c5385c57deeb7053d3d7d81d59
tar xvf urllib3-1.16.tar.gz  && cd urllib3-1.16/
python setup.py install
```