# Can't create virtual env with pip in Ubuntu - No module named urllib3

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I am having the following problem when trying to create a virtual env on Ubuntu:

```
$ mkvirtualenv test
New python executable in /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/utils.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/compat.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
ImportError: No module named urllib3
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 708, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 941, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 897, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 792, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/test/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I already try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973229/virtualenv-importerror-no-module-named-urllib3), worked fine, but using mkvirtualenv still no good.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue specific to using Anaconda. You can create a virtualenv with the default python:

```
mkvirtualenv test -p /usr/bin/python
```